# python-devがインストールできません

Tags: python

OSはOS 10.10.1 Yosemete
pythonのバージョンは3.4.3
です。

現在、mecab-pythonをインストールするためにpython-devをインストールしようとしています。

しかし、ターミナルで
brew install python-dev
と打っても
Error: No available formula for python-dev 
Searching formulae...
Searching taps...
と出てきて、

sudo port install python-dev
と打っても
Error: Port python-dev not found
と出て来ます。
python3-devで試してもだめでした。

どうしたらインストールできるんでしょうか・・・
助けてくださいよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ヘッダーファイルはすでにインストールされているはずです。次のコマンドを実行してみてください。Pythonのヘッダーファイルがどこにあるかを,Cコンパイラのオプションとして出力します。

`python-config --include`

mecabについてはこちらでテストしていませんが、次のようにしてCコンパイラのオプションを引き渡してconfigureを実行します。

`CFLAGS=$(python-config --include) ./configure`

この後`make`すればコンパイルが通るはずです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
python-config --include
を実行すると
-I/Users/Pikachu/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/include/python3.4m -I/Users/Pikachu/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/include/python3.4m
と出て来ました。
これはすでにインストールされているということでしょうか？

Comment: 使い方を追加しましたので、お試しください。うまくいかなければお知らせください。